# add a list into another list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a list as follows and I want to add it in another list:

```
Dim listRecord As New List(Of String)
listRecord.Add(txtRating.Text)
listRecord.Add(txtAge.Text)
listRace.Add(listRecord)
```

to obtain something like `{{r1,a1},{r2,a2},{r3,a3}}`, how can I achieve this in VB.Net?

Comment: Do you want a) to append one list onto the end of another, or b) one have a list where each item is also a list?

Comment: {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3},{x4,y4,z4},{x5,y5,z5},{x6,y6,z6},{and so on}}

Comment: Instead of nested lists, what you really should do is create a Class which represents a record, and then have a single list of records. A *little* more effort upfront but it will make your life way easier after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume from your question you want nested Lists, not to simply append one list onto the end of another?

```
Dim listRecord As New List(Of String)
listRecord.Add(txtRating.Text)
listRecord.Add(txtAge.Text)
listRace.Add(listRecord)

Dim records as new List(of List(of String))
records.Add(listRecord)
```

Hope this helps

**Update**
Reading them is like accessing any other list.
To get the first field in the first record

```
return records(0)(0)
```

second field in first record

```
return records(0)(1)
```

etc . . .

Comment: ok it works, but at a later time, how can i read an item at a particular index in listRecord? thank you

Answer (score 13):

You could use List's [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)

```
listRace.AddRange(listRecord)
```

or Enumerable's [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979.aspx):

```
Dim allItems = listRace.Concat(listRecord)
Dim newList As List(Of String) = allItems.ToList()
```

if you want to eliminate duplicates use Enumerable's [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx):

```
Dim uniqueItems = listRace.Union(listRecord)
```

The difference between `AddRange` and `Concat` is:

- [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) produces a new sequence(well, actually is doesn't produce it immediately due to `Concat`'s deferred execution, it's more like a query) and you have to use `ToList` to create a new list from it.
- [`List.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) adds them to the same `List` so modifes the original one.

Comment: euhh ok, but at a later time, how can i read an item at a particular index in listRecord? thank you !

Comment: @Naad: I'm not sure if i understand you corretcly. You keep the reference to listRecord. So you could always read items via index: `Dim item=listRecord(10)`

Comment: i have a For Loop and in each loop i want to append a list onto the end of another (in my case append listRecord to listRace) obtaining listRace={{listrecord1},{listrecord2},{listrecord3}}

Comment: @Naad: Ok, you need nested lists as i can see from your accepted answer. You can get the reference to your original list via the outer list's index. `listrecord3=listRecord(1)(2)` (asssuming `listRace` is the second list in the outer list)

Comment: i made a mistake, listrecord and listRecord is the same list :/ but still listRecord(x)(y) doesnt seem to function

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for the same problem **and I found the solution**. I think this is exactly what you want (To set list items inline, instead of using functions of List(of()) class):

```
Dim somelist As New List(Of List(Of String)) From {New List(Of String) From {("L1 item1"), ("L1 item2")}, New List(Of String) From {("L2 item1"), ("L2 item2")}}
```

I admit that it looks complicated, but this is the structure.

In order to make the code look simpler, I add the following screen snip showing the code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwym7xq7e2wvwto/Capture12.PNG?dl=0